# Why does this pattern of large primes appear in this series?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I tried calculating the series $z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + 1/4$ using fractions to keep the values exact.  There's little cancellation, so the resulting integers diverge quickly.  But a surprising pattern emerged:

(This is Mathematica code but simple enough to read as pseudo-code)

```
    c = 1/4;
    z = 0;
    Do[
     z = z^2 + c;
     Print[FactorInteger[Numerator[z]]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

The output for each iteration is a {prime factor, exponent} list for z's numerator:

```
(*

{{1,1}}

{{5,1}}

{{89,1}}

{{5,1},{4861,1}}

{{101,1},{16479949,1}}

{{5,1},{89,1},{16589129306474069,1}}

{{29,1},{1549,1},{3106941419772552263731365858433609,1}}

{{5,1},{4861,1},{34469,1},{57804649748579254030495262238075339775807968204231935465462520396029,1}}

*)
```

Notice that all the exponents are 1, and there are always a small number of factors that includes VERY large primes. The denominators are all powers of 2, so it's not just that the small primes are getting cancelled.  I can't imagine why a pattern like this would emerge, and I'm hoping someone can give a more insightful explanation than my officemate's "It just... DOES."    :-)

Update: A similar pattern of large primes of power 1 emerges with all the other fractions I tried.  The only small prime factors or higher exponents that appear are the ones in the original numerator; other than that, it's all large primes to power 1.

Comment: I think this is related to $a2^b\pm1$ being likely to be a prime number if $2^b>a$ or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps find a formula for $a_n$, which must be along the lines of $a_n=a_0^{2^n}+?a_0^{2^n-1}+?a_0^{2^n-2}+\dots$

Comment: I wouldn't underestimate the wisdom of your officemate's insight :-)

Comment: Write $z_n$ for your term, with $z_0=0$ and $z_{n+1}=z_{n}^2+\frac{1}{4}$.

Then let $x_n=2^{2^n} z_n$, so you get $$x_{n+1}=2^{2^{n+1}}z_{n+1}=(2^{2^n}z_n)^2 + 2^{2^n-2}=x_n^2+2^{2^n-2}$$

Note that $x_{n}$ is odd for $n>0$. So $x_n$ is your numerator.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the strong law of small numbers at work?  A random odd number is squarefree with probability $\frac{8}{\pi^2}\approx 81\%$ so seeing even 8 in a row still has probability almost 20%.  The large primes are definitely more surprising, but even that doesn't seem entirely absurd to me...

Answer (score 1):

With some starting points and some $c$ you **will** get some numerators divisible by the square of a prime.  Thus the numerator of $x_n$ is divisible by $3^2$ for all even $n$ if $c \equiv 8 \mod 9$ (this includes a fraction $a/b$ where $b$ is coprime to $3$ and $a +b$ is divisible by $9$)  and $x_0 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.  Or if you want to stick to $c = 1/4$, the numerator of $x_2$ will be divisible by $13^2$ if $x_0 \equiv \pm 44 \mod 13^2$.

EDIT: In general, for a given prime $p$, any $c$  and any starting point, the function $f(x) = x^2 + c \mod p$ on the integers mod $p$ has some fixed points and/or cycles, and with any starting point $x_0$ the iteration $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ will eventually (and in fact pretty soon, because the function is almost two-to-one), hit one of those fixed points or cycles, and thus is eventually constant or periodic.  Usually there are only a few of these cycles or fixed points.  The value $0$ may or may not be in a cycle (it won't be a fixed point unless $c \equiv 0 \mod p$).  Thus if a small prime $p$ doesn't occur in the numerator in the first few iterations, it won't ever occur.  This somewhat explains the prevalence of large primes.
Similarly for $p^2$ instead of $p$.

Comment: Right, that's what I mentioned in the Update paragraph.

Comment: My second example, with $x_0 \equiv \pm 44 \mod 13^2$, does **not** have $13^2$ in the original numerator.

Comment: Or if $c \equiv 3 \mod 7^2$ and $x_0 \equiv \pm 3 \mod 7^2$, you get $x_n \equiv 0 \mod 7^2$ for all $n \equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Comment: If $c \equiv 3 \mod 7^2$ and $x_0 \equiv \pm 22 \mod 49$, you get $x_n \equiv 0 \mod 7^2$ for all $n \equiv 0 \mod 3$.